# What does "you are forgiven to do something" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "**Everyone doesn't feel uncomfortable when Apple raises the price of its iPhones**"? And why does the author say "Apple is forgiven....."?

> A corollary is that the more innovative the new features are, the more a price increase can be justified. **Add the name “Apple” to that, and you are forgiven to push the price envelope even further.** Introducing the iPhone X along with two versions of the iPhone 8 seems a clever strategy. First, by skipping the “9th” generation and directly going to the “10th” generation, Apple sends a strong signal that the new device is a radical and discontinuous innovation over the prior generation iPhones. Second, by using the Roman numeral “X,” not the usual Arabic “10,” the company underscores the discontinuity. Third, the distinct design that removed the iconic iPhone’s home button backs up the “story” about the new device.

Source: http://fortune.com/2017/09/14/apple-iphone-x-price/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In present-day AmE,  we are **forgiven for pushing**, that is **forgiven** + **for** + the **-ing** form. Here, the complement of **forgiven** is infinitival, ***to push* the price envelope**.

You  are (that is, one is) forgiven for "pushing the price envelope", business-writer argot for "setting the price of something rather high, higher than it has been set heretofore.

To *push the envelope* in some domain or endeavor (speed, price, distance, altitude, etc) means to strive to go beyond existing constraints and best the standing achievement, to set a new record. It is often used in engineering contexts. For example:

https://www.nasa.gov/content/pushing-the-envelope

In business writing you will often find the writer coopting an idiom and sticking a business-related adjective in.

> To push the *price* envelope.

So, going forward, if you don't understand a phrase in a business article, one of the first things to do is to strike the business-word from the phrase and then look to see if it is an idiom, especially if it follows this pattern:

> To push the <strike>price</strike> envelope.

Why can Apple be forgiven for setting the price as high as a plane flying at Mach 2? For two reasons: technological innovation and the cachet of the Apple brand itself:

> Add the name “Apple” to that [that is, to "innovation"], and you are
>   forgiven ...

This form, where the verb is cast as an imperative supplemented by a clause with **and**  ("Add ..., and ... ") is to be understood as a kind of conditional:  *If|When you add...*

> Take your shoes off and you will feel how hot the sand is.
>
> Stand here and you will see the bird's nest.
>
> Study for the test and you will do well.

Since the construction is a passive one, those who do the forgiving are unstated, but one assumes the author means "customers": customers might be ticked off at Apple for setting the price so high, but they will forgive Apple when they recognize the innovation, and they will be willing to spend extra for the Apple brand in any case.